# Return a random number range between 0 and a variable

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have some JSP that holds a number inside a variable, it looks something like this

`<c:set var="myNumber" value="${fn:length(myItems)}" />`

What I'd like to do is create another variable that gives a random number between 0 and the number stored in this variable. I know that you can use Math.random with Java to do this but I'm unsure how to modify it to accept a variable in place of the 100:

`<c:set var="myNumber"><%= java.lang.Math.round(java.lang.Math.random() * 100) %></c:set>`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access JSTL variable value in scriptlets, you can do so by calling the [getAttribute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) method on the appropriately scoped object. JSTL works entirely with scoped attributes, either at `page`, `request` or `session` scope. JSTL variables are actually attributes, and by default are scoped at the page context level. Try Example below. It will generate a random number between 0 and the value of variable `myNumber` and then the random number is set to `myRandomNumber` variable.

```
<c:set var="myNumber" value="${fn:length(myItems)}"/>
<%
    int myNumber = (int)pageContext.getAttribute("myNumber");
    int randomNumber = (int)(java.lang.Math.random() * (myNumber + 1));
    pageContext.setAttribute("randomNumber", randomNumber);
%>
<c:set var="myRandomNumber" value="${randomNumber}"/>
```

Comment: I'm glad that it helped.